# How could i fetch local ip address using PHP?

Tags: php, ip

I want to fetch Local IP address instead of remote IP address in PHP?

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` will return the IP

Comment: `$_SERVER` MAY HELP U

Comment: No, By using $_SERVER we can fetch only public IP address..Which is like 2.50.33.xxx
Local ip address like 198.160.1.xx

Comment: You can not get(access) local IP address of the remote user

Answer (score 0):

U can try this (worked for me)-

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Or-

```
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

Or-

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
```

### Update-

The way of finding IP address of a user in PHP can be 2-

1.**Using *getenv()*** - `getenv()` is used to get the value of an environment variable in PHP like this-

```
// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip()
{
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

2.**Using *$_SERVER*** - $_SERVER is an array that contains server variables created by the web server like this-

```
// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip()
{
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

U can use whatever way u want :).

Comment: This will return public ip address, not local..

Comment: Answer updated, please try and let me know if u don't have your solution

Comment: Still getting public IP address...As per my research, there is no way t fetch ip address using PHP. 
Thanks for the help.